# How to use property binding with asynchronous data?

Tags: angular, angular7, property-binding

I'm trying to connect an existent front-end with a new back-end. One of the front-end component has the following template:

```
<simplex-chart [numbers]="someData"></simplex-chart>
```

The existent front-end is rather a prototype in which data is static. In the new release, the data is not anymore static but they come from databses, via services. Hence, the property binding above doesn't work any more.
How could I adapt it for data comming asynchronously ? I've seen constructs like {{ somedata | async }} but I didn't find any way to bind that to an input property.
Any suggestion ?
Many thanks in advance,
Nicolas

Answer (score 3):

Try to use `@Input()numbers: number[] = [];` to have empty array as default value when you don't have the data from parent yet.

Answer (score 3):

try the following:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="someData | async as data"> 
   <simplex-chart [numbers]="data"></simplex-chart>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 1):

If `someData` it's  and observable you can use the **pipe** `async` do something like this:

```
<simplex-chart [numbers]="someData | async"></simplex-chart>
```

More info about the pipe async here:

https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe

**Update:**

Seeing that  `simplex-chart` uses a `@Input() numbers: number[]`, you can add a ngIf until the data is loadad. It would look something like this:

```
<simplex-chart *ngIf="someData" [numbers]="someData"></simplex-chart>
```

Comment: I've tried before posting but it doesn't work, raising the following exception:
ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument:  for pipe 'AsyncPipe'
    at invalidPipeArgumentError (common.js:4013)
    at AsyncPipe.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/common.js.AsyncPipe._selectStrategy (common.js:4624)
    at AsyncPipe.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/common.js.AsyncPipe._s
    ...
And no, someData is not an Observable but an array of numbers wich has been subscribed from an Observable by the component code.

Comment: Could you make an example in stackblitz.com? As the error says, someData is an array, so, what's the error you are having when you put `<simplex-chart [numbers]="someData"></simplex-chart>` directly? Seems like you don't need the pipe because you work with an array directly

Comment: Yes, I confirm that someData is an array of numbers. The error is: "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined". The source line raising the exception is: "data: this.numbers.map(p => p - 15)" where numbers is "@Input()numbers: number[];" I will provide an example.

Comment: My understanding is that ngif would only perform a test but won't manage the asynchronous charcater of the data. Of course, doing it would take more time and this might give more chances to the operation to finish before. But I don't think that would be the solution.

Comment: It checks if the value exists, and if it has value renders the simplex chart

Comment: Because it waits until the numbers are defined to render

Comment: Yes, it works, thanks. But I still don't understand why. If the value doesn't exist it doesn't render it which is not what I want. I want to render the value if it exists and, if not, to wait until it comes. In the present case it works because, as I said, doing the ngif takes more time giving the async data a chance to come.

Comment: Okay, so it waits until the data is defined. I got it, thanks.